# mysql php group_concat Limit Clause how to fetch 3-4 records only (limited number)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch only limited rows output in the below mentioned query, please help

```
$sql12 = "SELECT group_concat(concat(firm_name, '- ',city,', ',mobile,'.') SEPARATOR ' ') as Result FROM  reg_dealer WHERE pincode = '$myvalue'";
$q12 = mysql_query($sql12);
$rows12= mysql_num_rows($q12);
while($res12= mysql_fetch_array($q12))
{
$res12['Result'];
$mobile = $_GET['mobile'];
$reply_message = "Greetings. Please find the nearest Partner - ".$res12['Result']."";
```

Comment: just add limit 0, 3 in your query

Comment: SELECT group_concat(concat(firm_name, '- ',city,', ',mobile,'.') SEPARATOR ' ') as Result FROM  reg_dealer WHERE pincode = '$myvalue' limit 0, 3

Comment: no working guys, i am getting all the  7 entry mapped with requested pincode

Comment: somewhere i have read that You can solve your issue by constructing a subquery with LIMIT 3, then in an outer query apply GROUP_CONCAT to the result of that subquery. but not able to apply

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
 $sql12 = "SELECT group_concat(concat(firm_name, '- ',city,', ',mobile,'.') SEPARATOR ' ') as result FROM (select * FROM reg_dealer WHERE pincode = '$myvalue' LIMIT 0, 3) as data";
    $q12 = mysql_query($sql12);
    $rows12 = mysql_num_rows($q12);
    while($res12= mysql_fetch_array($q12))
    {
         $res12['Result'];
         $mobile = $_GET['mobile'];
         $reply_message = "Greetings. Please find the nearest Partner - ".$res12['Result']."";
    }
```

Comment: Ankit i am getting all the records, on this site i have read a user comment -  You can solve your issue by constructing a subquery with LIMIT 3, then in an outer query apply GROUP_CONCAT to the result of that subquery.

Comment: try this SELECT group_concat(concat(firm_name, '- ',city,', ',mobile,'.') SEPARATOR ' ') as result FROM (select * FROM  reg_dealer WHERE pincode = '$myvalue' LIMIT 0, 3) as data

Comment: have edited the solution try the above one hope will work for you:) if not then let me know.

Comment: Ankur getting error mysql_fetch_array expected parameter 1

Comment: is it possible to share your table structure

Comment: Yes you can ask your query.

Comment: Is it possible to share your table structure with dummy data then will try it at my end and recognize the problem with the query.